# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, exception, sap-commerce-cloud

Few of the API call getting RunTime Exception and not able to understand the root cause.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/02/28 14:04:34.738 | java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/02/28 14:04:34.738 |     at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:463) ~[rxjava-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/02/28 14:04:34.738 |     at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.firstOrDefault(BlockingObservable.java:192) ~[rxjava-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/02/28 14:04:34.738 |     at com.hybris.charon.CharonHandler.invoke(CharonHandler.java:288) ~[charon-1.2.1-RC1.jar:1.2.1-RC1]
```

Comment: Add the code where this error is being thrown.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: looks like Charon is waiting for token but getting timeout from token api.

Answer (score 0):

The blocking task which was invoked & being executed synchronously was timed out during the HTTP Request made through exposed REST Service. Please verify whether the thread which executed the blocking task was running asynchronously.